# Download a database under Excel format

Tags: excel, mongodb, download, fastapi

I am creating an application in which there is a button to download the database. I am working in the back with FastAPI and MongoDB.

```
filtered_db = db.collection.find(base_query)

docs = []
async for doc in docs:
    docs.append(Document(**doc).dict())

df = pd.DataFrame(docs)

return Response(content=df, media_type="text/csv")
```

Here is a sample of my code, filtering database that is in MongoDB, then using a model and transforming it into a dataframe. But this is not working, could you help me?
I have the error: `"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'"`

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are trying to append the retrieved `filtered_db` data to a `docs` list. You're instead reading from an empty list `docs`

It should be

```py
filtered_db = db.collection.find(base_query)

docs = []
async for doc in filtered_db:
```

If you are trying to export the data to a `.csv` file then you can use the  [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function

```py
return df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

If you want your API to show the `.csv` file in the Response, you can do it like this

```py
return Response(content=df.to_csv(), media_type="text/csv")
```

---

By the way, here is a complete FastAPI example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pandas as pd


app = FastAPI()

class Document(BaseModel):
    id: int
    column1: str
    column2: str

filtered_db = [
    {"id": "1", "column1": "c1-value1", "column2": "c2-value1"},
    {"id": "2", "column1": "c1-value2", "column2": "c2-value2"}
]

async def read_data(data: list):
    docs = []

    for doc in data:
        docs.append(Document(**doc).dict())

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=docs)
    return df


@app.get("/xlsx")
async def get_excel():
    df = await read_data(filtered_db)
    # export data to csv
    # df.to_csv('output.csv')
    return Response(content=df.to_csv(), media_type="text/csv")
```